# How to map assosiative array in React/ES6? Starts an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, mapping

The array is generated following way:

```
for(var i = start; i <= end;i+=step) {
    arr[i] = i + 'is the number';
}
```

Array structure looks like this

```
arr = [
1100: "1100 is the number",
1101: "1101 is the number",
1102: "1102 is the number",
1103: "1103 is the number",
1104: "1104 is the number",
1105: "1105 is the number",
];
```

and so on.

This array will be mapped into a list element in React.

```
render() {
    const list = this.arr;
    const timeList = list.map((element) =>
        <li>{element}</li>
        );


    return (
      <div className="App" >
        {timeList}
      </div>
    );
```

It works fine with the regular arrays, but using this one gives me an infinite loop.

Why is this happening and what are the possibilities to solve this ?

Thank you

UPDATE:
Found out that
"If you use named indexes, JavaScript will redefine the array to a standard object.
After that, some array methods and properties will produce incorrect results."

But still no solution to the problem

Comment: Your array structure is not valid JavaScript code. *"If you use named indexes, JavaScript will redefine the array to a standard object."* That's just wrong. Every array is an object. However, not all properties of an array are considered elements of the array. So it could very well be that your using arrays in a way that they are not supposed to be used. However, the code you have won't result in an infinite loop. Without a complete example it's difficult to help.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have arr variable inside your render function. Your issue is '`this.arr`'. Remove '`this`' from here and use '`arr`'.

Here is the working code, I have checked on my local react setup it prints the array:

```
render() {
    const arr = [
         1100: "1100 is the number",
         1101: "1101 is the number",
         1102: "1102 is the number",
         1103: "1103 is the number",
         1104: "1104 is the number",
         1105: "1105 is the number",
     ];
    const list = arr;
    const timeList = list.map((element, idx) =>
        <li key={idx}>{element}</li>
        );


    return (
      <div className="App" >
        {timeList}
      </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: nice try, but still infinite loop.

Comment: @Giedrius  It is working correctly on my end. Here is simple github repo try using this and check once. Github repo: https://github.com/upasanaa/react-array-infinite-loop-issue

Answer (score 0):

Might be the i <= end? have you tried start.length, etc etc.

another solution is try switch to map() function.

Please let me know.

Comment: Please do not use answers to ask clarification questions.